# Split text file in random halves based on category

Tags: text-processing, split, random

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
n03250847/n03250847_0.JPEG n03250847
n03250847/n03250847_1.JPEG n03250847
...
n03250847/n03250847_499.JPEG n03250847
...
n03255030/n03255030_0.JPEG n03255030
n03255030/n03255030_1.JPEG n03255030
...
n03255030/n03255030_499.JPEG n03255030
```

The last number after the space is the category number. I have 200 different categories, and per category there are 500 lines (0 to 499). I would like to split this file in two, where each resulting file contains 100 random categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind splitting the file based on category and working with the pieces, you could do:

```
split -l 500 -a 3 infile
rnd=( $(printf %s\\n x??? | shuf -n 100) )
cat "${rnd[@]}" > rand1
rm "${rnd[@]}"
cat x??? > rand2
rm x???
```

This `split`s the file into 200 pieces of 500-lines each (so one piece per category) and selects 100 random pieces via `shuf` - the file names are saved in an array - `rnd`. It then merges the pieces listed in the array into `rand1`, deletes them and merges the remaining pieces into `rand2` and delete those too. This solution assumes that lines in your file are grouped by category and that the only file names matching `x???` in the current directory are the ones produced by the `split` command.

Comment: Marvelous, this works excellent, thank you Don! Can I ask for one addition? Suppose I want to randomly shuffle the order of the lines within each category. Now they are sorted 0 to 499. How can I shuffle them randomly?

Comment: Use  `split` with `--filter` just like in the answer to your other question this time using the `$FILE` param e.g.: `split -l 500 -a 3 --filter='shuf >$FILE' infile` this will shuffle the lines in each category before saving them into `x???` piece. Then execute the remaining commands...